# How to write to files using the fwrite() function in php

Tags: php

My value in array and i want to prient each value in in seprates line

Comment: What isn't working about it so far?

Comment: a pure example of bad question

Answer (score 2):

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php

Please google next time...

Comment: New Line not go to the new line these print the records the same same line

Comment: well then just print "\nMy line then" the character "\n" means **go to a new line** just put it where ever you want...

Answer (score 2):

Use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`. Single quotes interpret less special characters than double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the luxury of php5:

```
file_put_contents($filename, "My name is Alok Ranjan Dubey.\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, use `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`, because line endings in Windows are different than in Unix.